# Discord.py - How would I go about making a command that will allow server admins to block the bot from responding in specified channels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My bot is in a few servers now and one of the main bits of feedback I've gotten is that server admins would like to block the bot from responding in certain channels without having to go through Discord's permissions manager. However I am unsure of where to start with this so I thought I'd reach out here and see if I can get any advice or code snippets to use!

Basically the admin would use like `!fg ignore 'channel name or id'` and then somewhere the bot would store this and not respond, and then similarly if they use `!fg unignore 'channel name or id'` it would then remove that from the list or where ever its stored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example I've made to get this working:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

ignoredChannels = [] # List of all the ignored channels, you can use a text file instead if you prefer

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "fg!"); 

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in ignoredChannels:
        return # If the channel is in the ignored list - return
    else:
        await client.process_commands(message) # Otherwise process the commands

@client.command()
async def ignore(ctx, channelID):
    if int(channelID) not in ignoredChannels:
        ignoredChannels.append(int(channelID)) # Add the channel if it hasn't been added yet
        await ctx.send("Successfully added the channel to the ignored list!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Channel was already inside the ignored list!") # Otherwise warn user that the channel is already ignored



@client.command()
async def unignore(ctx, channelID):
    try:
        ignoredChannels.remove(int(channelID)) # Attempt to remove the channel from the list
        await ctx.send("Successfully removed the channel from the ignored list!")
    except:
        await ctx.send("This channel is already removed!") # If fails, warn the user that the channel is already removed


client.run(your_bot_token) # Run the bot with your token
```

How it works is it checks if the channel ID exists in the list every time a message gets sent, if it finds the channel in the list it will return and do nothing otherwise if the channel is not in the list, it will continue processing the commands in that channel.

If you want to only allow admins to use the command you can add `@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)` under each of the `@client.command()` lines.

Hope it helps and happy coding :)

Comment: How would I be able to call the list from another python file as I am using cogs for my bot?

Comment: You will need to define a function in that file and have it return the list, you can then import it into your bot file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep the channels ids in a list then in the bots on_message function check if the message is not in that channel and if not then run your commands.